# PHP finfo_file() shows incorrect MIME for JS files starting with comment

Tags: javascript, php, css, file-upload

I want to test my uploaded file whether it is a plain/text file or not. For this I'm using the following code:

```
private function isUploadedFileTextFile() {
    return finfo_file(
             finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE),
             $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
           ) == 'text/plain';
}
```

It was working in most of the cases but when I try to upload a js file which starts with comments (and the same with CSS) then it says it is plain/text and it lets my file to be uploaded.
I've read about a bug in finfo_file ( https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53035 ) and I've also heard that this finfo_open is not really reliable because it's trying to figure out the mime type based on the content, but I'm curious, what would you suggest to do in order to allow only plain/text files to be uploaded? (i.e. exclude these script files and stylesheets also)

edit 1: Strange that the `$_FILES['file']['type']` shows correctly that it is `application/x-javascript` but I've heard I should not rely on this either. Or should I use double check?

Thanks!

Comment: when it comes to uploads, trust nothing, verify everything.

Comment: Yes, It is true, but what do you mean now by this? My question was exactly that how to verify it, should I use both the two options or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: the problem is in what way will the file be accessed (particularly over the internet) after it is uploaded.

Comment: There will be patterns in each line of the uploaded text file and I will store these lines (with slight modifications) in the database, so I should make sure that the uploaded file is really a plain/text file and does not contain any JS or other script codes.

Comment: I expect I would not trust MIME type and instead search the file and escape dangerous characters, or exclude files that appear to indicate they are not the types of files I'm looking for based on the contents.